# Problems with understanding a requirement in a technical document

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, technical

I'm following the advice of a user who answered a [question on StackOverflow](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/108453/nist-pqc-minimum-number-of-digital-signatures).

Page 15 section 4.A.4 of [NIST call for proposal](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Post-Quantum-Cryptography/documents/call-for-proposals-final-dec-2016.pdf) (the 2016 one) says:

> For the purpose of estimating security strengths, it may be assumed that the attacker has access to signatures for no more than 2⁶⁴ chosen messages;

My original question was where I'd find NIST's requirements about the minimum number of signatures that can be generated with a *digital signature scheme* (let's say some algorithm).

I don't manage to get the meaning about a *minimum number of possible signatures* from this sentence, as @DannyNiu seems to understand it in his response (i.e. a signature scheme has to provide at least this lower bound number of signatures).

What I rather understand from that sentence is that it's just an assumption for the security evaluation, i.e. the evaluation is done assuming an attacker has less than 2⁶⁴ chosen plaintexts with their matching signatures. We ideally want signature schemes with a virtually unlimited amount of possible signatures.

Maybe someone could try to explain this sentence to me, in case the @DannyNiu is right, or otherwise confirm that I understand it correctly.

Edit:

I should provide some background/context: This document is (among others) about so-called *hash-bashed signatures*. Current signature schemes can be used endlessly (i.e. you can create an infinite number of signatures). Hash-based signature schemes, on the other side, have a limited number of signatures that can be generated. So NIST should have a requirement like *any proposed signature scheme SHALL be usable for at least x signatures*.

2^64 would imho indeed be a reasonable value, but it might also be 2^50 or 2^80.

[For the purpose of ELU, 2⁶⁴ is merely an extremely large number, approximately 18.4 trillion.]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149367/discussion-on-question-by-radix-problems-with-understanding-a-requirement-in-a-t); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.